# Text Predictive Suggestions on edit-text like in line app android

Tags: android, android-edittext, autosuggest, textwatcher

I want to show my custom predictive text suggestions over the edit-text like line app show stickers for keywords. E.g. When you write hello/hi, line show stickers of hand and hello as a suggestion. User can select the word from the suggestion and the keyword which user choose from the suggestion will be highlighted in the edit-text (May be bold/Color Change).
[image]

I attached the real time example which i want to achieve. please have a look give suggestions to achieve this!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [AutoCompleteTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) which is actually an `EditText`(a bit misleading I think). When you use an `AutoCompleteTextView` you can supply a custom adapter to feed it suggestions like so:

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, list, R.id.row_layout, new String[] { "Name", "Phone" }, new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.phone });
autoCompleteField.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Yes i Know about AutoCompleteTextView, but I need custom build Autocomplete as i attached the design above.

Comment: Hi @roarster did you find any solution yet?